# Out of memory error native Image decode Error while loading image to gallery

Tags: java-me

I am trying to load image from a folder into my application, the code I am using is

```
FileConnection fc = null;
DataInputStream in = null;
DataOutputStream out = null;

try {
  fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///e:/Images/Abc.jpg");
  int length = (int)fc.fileSize();//possible loss of precision may throw error
  byte[] data = null;
  if (length != -1) {
    data = new byte[length];
    in = new DataInputStream(fc.openInputStream());
    in.readFully(data);
  }
  else {
    int chunkSize = 112;
    int index = 0;
    int readLength = 0;
    in = new DataInputStream(fc.openInputStream());
    data = new byte[chunkSize];
    do {
      if (data.length < index + chunkSize) {
        byte[] newData = new byte[index + chunkSize];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);
        data = newData;
      }
      readLength = in.read(data, index, chunkSize);
      index += readLength;
    } while (readLength == chunkSize);
    length = index;
  }
  Image image = Image.createImage(data, 0, length);
  image = createThumbnail(image);
  ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem(null, image, 0, null);
  mForm.append(imageItem);
  mForm.setTitle("Done.");
  fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///e:/Images/Abc.jpg");
  if(!fc.exists()){
      try{
      fc.create();                                                                                                                                                                              
      }catch(Exception ce){System.out.print("Create Error: " + ce);}
  }
  out = new DataOutputStream(fc.openOutputStream());
  out.write(data);
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
  StringItem stringItem = new StringItem(null, ioe.toString());
  mForm.append(stringItem);
  mForm.setTitle("Done.");
}
finally {
  try {
    if (in != null) in.close();
    if (fc != null) fc.close();
  }
  catch (IOException ioe) {}
```

hope it can be the problem with image I tried to resize the image

```
    private Image createThumbnail(Image image)
{
    int sourceWidth = image.getWidth();
    int sourceHeight = image.getHeight();
    int thumbWidth = 18;
    int thumbHeight = 23;

    Image thumb = Image.createImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
    Graphics g = thumb.getGraphics();

    for (int y = 0; y < thumbHeight; y++)
    {
    for (int x = 0; x < thumbWidth; x++)
    {
    g.setClip(x, y, 1, 1);
    int dx = x * sourceWidth / thumbWidth;
    int dy = y * sourceHeight / thumbHeight;
    g.drawImage(image, x - dx, y - dy, Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);

    }
    }

    Image immutableThumb = Image.createImage(thumb);
    return immutableThumb;
}
```

Still it returns an exception out of memmory native image deocde error, Somebody pls help me to sort it out

Answer (score 0):

This may occur becuase of two reason.

1. Image size: In some phones due to small heap size not device does not load image so try with smaller image size.
2. Second reason may be image is corrupt so try with another image.